# How do I disable some orders?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

i am creating such module in which i have created one extra attribute in order database table named - is_archive which will have 0 or 1 value. and created mass action named is_archive. 
all selected orders will save 1 in database order is_archive.

```
$orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_ids');

   if(!empty($orderIds) && $activeArchive == 1 )
   {
       try{
           foreach ($orderIds as $o)
           {
               $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($o);
               $orders->setIsArchived("1")->save(); // here is_archive will have 1 in database
           }
       }
```

now i want that orders which have 1 in is_archive attribute will not appear in sales order grid.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app/code/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` file

at line number 59

add below line   `$collection->addFilter('is_archived', 1);`

Comment: thank you for suggestion.. I know it will definitely work. but it will have change in core part. i dont want any changes in core. i have created my grid.php so i will try by writing this in my file.

Comment: you overide it in local file and do changes

Comment: and if my answer is useful that please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

if  you have talking about  **Sales order grid**  then you ***should  aware that sales  order grid*** is coming from  **sales_flat_order_grid** database tablef 
instead of `sales_flat_order`, So

*Either you should create also*  create  field `is_archive` at `sales_flat_order_grid` or you need to  join `sales_flat_order` table with `sales/flat_grid` collection.

Then as mention by  jigs parmar, you need go

```
app/code/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

and add this field in collection filter